# I have an employee List , i want to get the name of an employee whose salary is min by using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code and I want to simplify it.

```
int minSalary = empList.Min(e => e.salary);
var emp = empList.Where(e => e.salary == minSalary).FirstOrDefault(); 
string empName = emp= != null ? emp= .Name : string.Empty;
```

Comment: this is not even correct syntax. in order to simplify use `MinBy` in `MoreLinq` library written by jon skeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the collection by the salary and then retrieving the first item is the one with the minimum `salary`. Retrieve it using `FirstOrDefault` and access the `Name` property using [`?.` operator (C# 6.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).
Last as `Name` might be `null` (if `FirstOrDefault` returned `null`) use [`??` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator)

```
string name = empList.OrderBy(e => e.salary).FirstOrDefault()?.Name ?? string.Empty;
```

For Prior C# 6.0:

```
var emp = empList.OrderBy(e => e.salary).FirstOrDefault();
var name = emp != null ? emp.Name : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With this syntax i am unable to access the Name property,i am getting errors 1.Syntax error, ':' expected  2.Invalid expression term '.'

Comment: @pandum - With what C# are you? If prior 6.0 see update

Comment: Ok . Now i understand thank you Mr.Gilad Green

Comment: @pandum - You are welcome :)

Comment: @pandum If this helped you solve the problem please consider marking question as solved by the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var employeeWithMinSalary = empList.OrderBy(e => e.Salary).FirstOrDefault();
string employeeWithMinSalaryName = employeeWithMinSalary?.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the collection by salary and then select the employee name as follows:

```
var name = empList.OrderBy(e => e.salary)
                  .Select(e => e.Name)
                  .FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```